# URL param passed as body param with Angular Resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I am using Angular (1) with `$resource`. One of my API request is failing because a URL param is passed as a request body param instead. Why is this happening?

```
/** @ngInject */
module.exports = function ($resource, API_URL) {
  return $resource(`${API_URL}/users`, null, {
    deactivateUser: {
      url: `${API_URL}/users/deactivate/:id`,
      method: 'put'
    },
    ...
  })
}
```

Used here:

```
User.deactivateUser({id})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage), you should specify `{id: '@id'}` as a second parameter to `$resource` function. For non-GET requests this will take `id` parameter and place it into url string, not request body.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6vfwq3y/) for that.